# Array of CString -> Memory Leak?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, cstring

I have an array of CStrings as a member in my class:

```
...
private:
 CString mStrings[7];
...
```

Although the destructor of the class gets called correctly my analysis tool tells me that there is a memory leak in each of the seven mStrings (each time I allocate and deallocate my class).

I thought that CStrings manage their memory themselves. Does the fact that I have them in an array change anything here?

Comment: Show code. What's your analysis tool, when does it run, how is your class being created, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: You will need to show us some code, having an array of strings doesn't change the fact that strings manage their own memory.If you are just creating an array like you show(on automatic storage), you don't need to anything explicitly to deallocate the allocated memory.

Comment: Could you provide more code that shows what you actually do and what the error is (preferably [sscce](http://sscce.org/))? ALso, is this microsoft's CString or another one? It's definitely not standard C++ so you should mention that.

Comment: There isn't much code around that. The object gets allocated via new, then deallocated via delete. The class itself doesn't contain much, mainly the CString array shown above. The tool I use for leak detection is "Memory Validator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that shouldn't be leaking. You don't get any leaks unless you allocate with `new` or `new[]` (or `malloc`) and don't free (with `delete`,`delete[]` or `free`) the memory.

In your case, the array is in automatic storage, so it automatically gets cleaned up. Also, `CString`s automatically manage their memory. Either it's a false positive, or there's some other code causing the issue.

Edit - Although a `CString` doesn't leak, a false positive might not be the case. Are you my any chance initializing as:

```
unsigned char* x = new unsigned char[10];
CString str(x);
```

and forgetting to `delete[] x`, or something similar?

Edit 2 - Maybe the error comes for un-deleted instances of your class:

```
struct X
{
private:
   CString mStrings[7];
};

//...
X* x = new X;
```

Comment: Well, I guess Memory Validator was just reporting a false positive here. I'm quite new to the Tool so I don't know to which extend I can trust it ;-)

Comment: @Boris: honestly, if it's giving a false positive on such a simple use case, I'd investigate a bit further. Either you're doing something very wrong in using it or this tool is completely useless for any practical purpose.

Comment: @Boris I also think a false positive is far fetched, how are you constructing the objects?

Comment: If a tool is giving a false positive - that tool should be chucked into the bin.

Comment: I'm initializing each CString like this mStrings[i] = "SomeBlaBla". So there are no undeleted char-arrays. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: PS: The tool is actually quite nice and found several leaks. So I'd be willing to forgive it some false positives ;-)

Comment: @Boris see new answer, another possible reason added.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a leap of faith here that `CString` is in fact a `char *`.

If this is the cast and the class has allocated them, then the destructor needs to deallocate them.

A delete of that object will be a shallow one. There is the problem.

But on a final note - what is the type of `CString`?

Comment: A Cstring is a MS specific data type that can represent a Unicode or ascii string. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx It's not a `char*`.

Comment: The question did not mention the platform. If it did I would have filled in that blank.